# Adding a text area by clicking a button-rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a list of 5 question text-fields in a form for a user to enter questions. I want a user to be able to add a question by clicking a "+" button.

how can i do this?

I have this for a sample:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@quiz, html: {class: 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages_question' %>
    <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: for the sake of others who maybe looking to solve the same problem, please check these rails-casts:
[196-nested-model-form-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=comments) [197-nested-model-form-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). Hope they help.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to set up with `javascript/coffeescript`,

Since it's Rails let's use `coffeescript`,

You should have a coffeescript file under your `app/assets/javascripts` folder named `quizzes.js.coffee`, if not you can create it.

(Also make sure that inside your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` you require that file or you have `require_tree .`

Now inside the file you can have something like this:

```
$ ->
  template = "<textarea name='quiz[content][INDEX]'></textarea>"
  index = $('textarea').length
  $('#js-add-question-row').click ->
    compiled_textarea = $(template.replace("INDEX", index))
    $('#someform').append(compiled_textarea)
    index = index + 1
```

And your html should look something like this:

```
<button id="js-add-question-row">+</button>
<form action="" method="" id="someform">
    <textarea name="quiz[content][0]"></textarea>
</form>
```

I added a javascript jsfiddle that shows you how it works http://jsfiddle.net/vjZ3g/

Comment: its working, but your way. could you explain a little so that I edit it to produce exact text_fields as the others?

Comment: @ben his way uses a template, so all of if your template is the same as the others then that's how they're the exact text_fields.  I have a similar answer that duplicates instead of using a template

Comment: @ben i did, its up above (when sorting by active)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

- Add an href link with id #samplehRefButton in your 5 question Quiz page.
- Put your server code for extra question in "rails_question_page"
- Add this script

code:

```
<script>
$('#samplehRefButton').click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault;
           $.get('your_rails_question_page', 
                            function (data) 
                            { $('#divQuestionsContainer').append(data); });
            });
</script>
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1):

This method involves using javascript to duplicate the text area element and increase its index.  It might be a bit over complex, but it kinda needs to be

http://jsfiddle.net/tprats108/9nfpP/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#js-add-question-row").click(function() {
    addQuestion();
  });
});

function addQuestion() {
  var question = $("textarea:last").clone();
  question = updateQuestion(question);
  question.insertAfter("textarea:last");
}

// This part substitutes out the index number and then increments the last by one
function updateQuestion(question) {
  var old_name = question.attr("name");
  var result = /\[[\d]+\]/.exec(old_name).toString();
  var old_index = result.slice(1, -1);
  var new_index = (parseInt(old_index, 10) + 1).toString();
  var new_name = old_name.replace(old_index, new_index);
  question.attr("name", new_name);
  return question
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create hidden input field(array) and push values of populated input field in it