# ruby on rails- how to add a text-area field by clicking a + button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have this simple form having 5 questions(text-areas) for a user to fill. I want a user to be able to add extra questions by clicking a "plus" button.

What is the easiest way to do this? please I am not so strong in JavaScript including jQuery, so I would kindly ask for some clear code and if possible little explanation.

this is my views:

```
<% question_numbering = 0 %>
<%= simple_form_for(@quiz, html: {class: 'form-vertical', id: 'someform' }) do |f| %>

    <div>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :rows => 3, :style => "width:80%", :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
        question <%= question_numbering += 1 %><br>
        <%= f.input_field :content, :placeholder => "enter your question."  %><br>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id = "js-add-question-row">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

pls NOTE the `question <%= question_numbering += 1 %>` is only for numbering the questions int the form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a text area by clicking a button-rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111122/adding-a-text-area-by-clicking-a-button-rails-4)

Comment: for the sake of others who maybe looking to solve the same problem, please check these rails-casts:
[196-nested-model-form-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=comments) [197-nested-model-form-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). Hope they help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could get an idea from this tutorial http://rbudiharso.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/dynamically-add-and-remove-input-field-in-rails-without-javascript/